# Circled texts over a SVG logo (top and bottom)

Tags: svg

I have a circled logo converted from EPS to SVG, which you can see here: [SVG circled text](https://configurator.kriger.nl/layout/frontend/products/svg/business-01-layer.svg)

I have used Boxy SVG to put the text inside the middle circled, but with no success. I understood I should put the text over a textPath, yet I am not familiar with that. What I need is like this:

[Logo circled text top and bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FKoT.png)

It has to be in the middle, regardless of the text length. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this attempt to render the text according to your specs. You will have to fine-tune the dimensions and location of the rendered text and adjust the presentation attributes but this version should get you started.

Concepts/techniques employed:

- Rendering text on a text path.
- Specifying an arc of an ellipse as a path (a semi-circle in this case).

  - Rotation of the arc
  - Orientation of the arc drawn ( through the sweep-flag )
- Defining an anchor point on text content.
- Anchoring text at a given offset into a path.
- Geometric transformation of the user coordinate system:

  - Horizontal/vertical flip

SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg
    viewBox="0 0 170.08 170.08" width="170.08" height="170.08" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
    <g transform="matrix(1.333333, 0, 0, -1.333333, 0, 170.080002)" id="g10">
        <g transform="scale(0.1)" id="g12">
            <!--
                The original content:
                <path id="path14" .../>
                   ...
                <path id="path414" .../>
            -->

            <!--
                The following 2 groups have been added
            -->
            <g
                transform="translate(637.5,637.5) scale(1, -1) translate(-637.5,-637.5)"
            >
                <path
                    id="top-text"
                    d="M 637.5 637.5 m -340 0 a 340 340 0 0 1 680 0"
                    fill="none"
                    stroke="none"
                />
                <text
                    font-family="Verdana"
                    font-size="90"
                    font-stretch="ultra-condensed"
                    fill="white"                
                    stroke="white"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    text-anchor="middle"
                >
                    <textPath
                        xlink:href="#top-text"
                        baseline-shift="10%"
                        font-stretch="ultra-condensed"
                        startOffset="50%"
                    >GOLFCLUB APELDOORN</textPath>
                </text>
            </g>

            <g
                transform="translate(637.5,637.5) scale(-1, 1) translate(-637.5,-637.5)"
            >
                <path
                    id="bottom-text"
                    d="M 637.5 637.5 m 340 0 a 340 340 180 0 0 -680 0"
                    fill="none"
                    stroke="none"
                />
                <text
                    font-family="Verdana"
                    font-size="90"
                    font-stretch="ultra-condensed"
                    fill="white"                
                    stroke="white"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    text-anchor="middle"
                >
                    <textPath
                        xlink:href="#bottom-text"
                        baseline-shift="-90%"
                        font-stretch="ultra-condensed"
                        startOffset="50%"
                    >055 - 52 55 55</textPath>
                </text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**References**

All necessary Information can be found in the [W3C SVG 1.1 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/).

Of particular interest are the sections on [paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html), [text](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html), and [coordinate systems](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html)

Comment: It is perfect, exactly as I needed. Thank you very much.